# Black image instead of blurring (fft and ifft)

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

The output of my program that blurs an image is a black screen with several white dots.

In this part, I make a kernel of a gaussian and pad it with zeros so to multiply its Fourier specter with the images' specter

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im1 = cv2.imread('beato.jpg', 0)
cv2.imshow('beato.jpg', im1)
cv2.waitKey(0) 

kernel = np.ones((3,3)) / 9
sz = (im1.shape[0] - kernel.shape[0], im1.shape[1] - kernel.shape[1])  # total amount of padding
kernel = np.pad(kernel, (((sz[0]+1)//2, sz[0]//2), ((sz[1]+1)//2, sz[1]//2)), 'constant')
kernel = np.fft.ifft(kernel)
```

In this part of the code I multiply the kernel Fourier specter with the images' specter. However, instead of a filtered image I get a black screen. What is my mistake?

```
filtered = np.real(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.fft2(im1) * np.fft.fft2(kernel)))

cv2.imshow('beato.jpg', filtered)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Comment: examine the ranges of your values.

Comment: `im1` is uint8, `filtered` is float. These are displayed differently by OpenCV. you might have to convert the output to uint8 before display, and do so carefully.

Comment: I think Cris is right. Use matplotlibs `plt.imshow` to analyse what you have in filtered image.